# Importing incremental backups in MySQL

Tags: mysql, backup

I'm using the following command to create an incremental backup in `MySQL`

```
mysqldump -uusername -ppassword db_name --flush-logs > D:\dbname_incremental_backup.sql
```

However the `sql` file is as big as a complete backup, and obviously importing it takes a long time as well. Could anybody tell me how to create **incremental backups** and import just the new data from each incremental backup rather than the whole database again?

I have read all the related articles in dev.mysql.com but still can not understand how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqldump` only creates full backups. There's no built-in functionality for incremental backups.

For that sort of thing you probably want [Percona xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/) but that will only work with InnoDB tables. This is usually not an issue since using MyISAM tables is considered extremely harmful.

Comment: I use InnoDB tables so that's not an issue. It surprises me that if I have to import the data on my db from yesterday I need to make a full backup

Answer (score 1):

By default a mysql dump will drop tables making an incremental update impossible. If you open up the resulting file, you will see something like:

`` DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `some_table_name`; ``

You can create a dump without dumping and creating new tables using the [--no-create-info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-create-info) option. To make your dump friendly to incremental imports, you should also use --skip-extended-import which will break inserts out into one insert statement per row. Combined with using `--force` on the import will mean that inserts for rows that exist will fail but the import will continue. You will end up seeing errors in the logs for rows that already exist, but new rows will be inserted as desired.

You should be able to export with the following command (I also recommend not typing the password in the command so that it won't appear in your history)

`mysqldump -u username -p --no-create-info --skip-extended-insert db_name --flush-logs > D:\dbname_incremental_backup.sql`

You can then import with the following command:

`mysql -u username -p --force db_name < D:\dbname_incremental_backup.sql`

Comment: This looks very promising! Any chance you've figured out a nicer way to achieve this?